# Custom ASP binding mechanism problem

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, binding

know ASP since about 6 months, and I've go hard problem. I've created my own DataBinding mechanism and I need some solution to do somthing like this:

I have this example code in my ASPX

```
<myButton id="someID" runat="server" Text="SomeText" BackColor="{SomeContext}" />
```

and I have in this control my property *Context* of type *Object*. I want to bind property which is inside *Context* to *BackColor* property. Name of the property from *Context* is *SomeContext* (in brackets). All I need is to use some *TypeConverter* or other technology to identify that there is a name inside **{}** and remember that name inside instance of *myButton* control. Any ideas???

I thought that I can use my own class inherited from *TypeConverter* and catch the moment of converting value *{SomeContext}* to Color (the *BackColor* property). I can catch this moment, but I have no info about target control, only empty context of String value. If anyone know how to get target property somehow, will be very!! helpful.

I've been searching web, and nothing...

Comment: Why won't regular databinding expressions work: (<%# ... %>)?

Answer (score 0):

You can set this in your code behind directly:

```
someID.BackColor = context.Color;
```

Comment: Yes, but I'm not using codebehind in current project. So maybe something else...?

Answer (score 0):

Ya might give ASP.NET [Custom Expression builders](https://web.archive.org/web/20210304125044/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/022509-1.aspx) a try.

Answer (score 0):

I won't use codebehind in my project. Website will be rendered from compiled customized aspx from database. I have special approach for my system, and my binding is a main part of it. Regular databinding expression won't help because it use ASP binding, which I don't want to use.

Comment: Custom Expression builders may help. I'll check this, and post answer here.

Comment: Unfortunately Expressions can't help here. I need some c# solution, like TypeConverter or approach how to generate IL like ASP expressions, but with IL code controlled by my class or something else written by me. So I think that here will help Reflection, but how?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I didn't find any solution of my problem, so I decided to use inner properties. I'll use ASPX code like this:

```
<myButton runat="server" ID="someID">
    <Binding>
       <Bind Target="BackColor" Source="ColorOfBackgroundFromContext" />
       <Bind Target="ForColor" Source="ColorOfForegroundFromContext" />
    </Binding>  
</myButton>
```